# c# and Unity, update records that have changed to a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, streamwriter

I'm trying to work with a CSV file that is essentially a database of records. On load of the game I Read in a record and instantiate a prefab button, one at a time with the correct text from the CSV file. It's not always the case that the index of the button will be the same as the index of the record where I got the information in the CSV file. So far I setup a Save function that I want certain records that have changed based on a tricks "name" field to reflect in the CSV file. What would be an easy way accomplish this?

Here is the code that Saves changes to the CSV and Unity gives me an exception, IOException: Sharing violation on path:

```
void WriteCSVFile()
{
    StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");
    StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");
        
    bool endOfFile = false;
    string header = strReader.ReadLine();
    strWriter.WriteLine(header);
    string data;
        
    while(!endOfFile)
    {
        data = strReader.ReadLine();
        strWriter.WriteLine(data);
        
        if(data == null)
        {
            endOfFile = true;
            break;
        }
        
        //dataValues is each row
        var dataValues = data.Split(',');
        
        if(dataValues[1] == trickName)
        {               
            dataValues[3] = currentXP.ToString();
            dataValues[4] = currentLevel.ToString();
            dataValues[5] = maximumXP.ToString();
            strWriter.WriteLine(dataValues[3]);
            strWriter.WriteLine(dataValues[4]);
            strWriter.WriteLine(dataValues[5]);             
        }
    }   
}
```

UPDATE: It seems to be working now but I need help with one more step. In the updated version of my save function you can see that I split each record by the commas into an array called dataValues. I make changes to the right fields in dataValues but now the text is separated into single lines when I do a Log statement. How do you think I can append the file back together to Write over the original CSV file? Here is the update to my save function: '''void WriteCSVFile(){

```
    string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");
    //StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");
    
    string[] data = txt.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
    
    foreach(string record in data){
        var dataValues = record.Split(',');

        if(dataValues.Length >= 6 && dataValues[1] == trickName){
            Debug.Log(dataValues[1]);
            //dataValues[3] = currentXP.ToString();
            //dataValues[4] = currentLevel.ToString();
            //dataValues[5] = maximumXP.ToString();
        } 
    }
    
    '''
```

Comment: Why did someone down vote my question? That is not very helpful at all. At least leave a comment explaining why you decided to down vote

Comment: I didn't down vote your question, but posting a YouTube link is not good practice. You should post your code here. What happens to this question if/when the link to YouTube is gone? If a solution it posted to your question, how will others find it if they have a similar problem? The video won't get indexed and become searchable for others. A big part of stackoverflow is helping the next person that has a similar issue as well as the person posting the question.

Comment: I did an edit including the code I'm using for the save function

Comment: ElloWorld, thanks for the update. As for your error, you cannot read from a file and write to a file at the same time. Your reader is locking the file from your writer. One option could be to write to a temp file and then copy the temp over the original at the very end.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was really hoping that I wouldn't have to make a temp file just to write it to the original. Seems like a lot of reading and writing to do in one step to just change a few values

Comment: For your new question you should make a new post instead of editing your current one. You can refer to this question in your new one. As I don't know what your data looks like and I don't know exactly what you expect the data to come out like the only thing I can suggest is... is your for/each loop the reason you get a record per line, if so is that not what you want?

Comment: Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. Please do not edit a question post in a way that invalidates reasonable answer posts. Fix the old post to ask its question & post a new question. I have rolled back your UPDATE to . (You can roll back my rollback, but please ask a new question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are assuming that every line contains at least 2 fields (by testing for `dataValues[1] == trickName`). Add a check for the length as well:

```
if (dataValues.Length >=6 && dataValues[1] == trickName)
{
   ...
}
```

Check for length (at least) 6, so that the use of `dataValues[5]` is valid.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer. My code seems to be working now

Comment: I need help with one more step. In the updated version of my save function you can see that I split each record (one row of data) by the commas into an array called dataValues. I make changes to the right fields in dataValues but now the text is separated into single lines when I do a Log statement. How do you think I can append the file back together to Write over the original CSV file?

Comment: There is a String.Join function that takes a separator (your comma) and a string array of parts to join. Write *all* lines (including skipped ones) to a new file

Comment: Write to a new file and then copy over the original. If you just overwrite the original and your app crashes, the original is destroyed

Answer (score 1):

I recommend extracting your CSV file into an in-memory collection, then dispose reader to ensure it's no longer accessing the file. Loop through the in-memory collection and use the writer to update the appropriate values. Also, it's best practice place StreamReader and StreamWriter instances inside using statements to ensure they are disposed properly.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will look into it.

Comment: If you add your code to the question, I can edit my answer and provide more details.

Comment: I did an edit including the code I'm using for the save function

Comment: I'm working on the solution right now, but it seems like it is going to work with an in-memory collection. Thank you!