# Join one-dimesional array to write over a CSV file with multiple records

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, join, streamwriter

[image: Original CSV file]

I am at the final step of a Save function and I need help figuring out how to structure the data back into the format of my CSV so that I can write over the original. This is a link to my other code/post helping me get to this point: [StackOverflow, first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903645/c-sharp-and-unity-update-records-that-have-changed-to-a-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment111266660_62903645) I have separated the records and changed the right values but now I need to join the records back in the same format as the CSV file to then write over the original CSV.

Here is my code:

```
string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");
        
string[] data = txt.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        
foreach(string record in data){
    var dataValues = record.Split(',');
            
    if(dataValues.Length >= 6 && dataValues[1] == trickName)
    {
        dataValues[3] = currentXP.ToString();
        dataValues[4] = currentLevel.ToString();
        dataValues[5] = maximumXP.ToString();
    } 
            
    foreach(string row in dataValues)
    {
        //prints out a one-dimesional array, single lines no commas
        Debug.Log(row);
    }           
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to loop back through your 'dataValues' string [] again.

Basically a for-loop using the counter as a trigger when it is > than 0 to add a comma before the next entry is added. Combine that with a 'WriteStream' to your files location and you will have it down. I would also recommend you change from foreach-loops to for-loops which will allow you to modify the memory references rather than copied version.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.. Make your post self-contained.Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. [ask]

Comment: @ElloWorld, Hans from the original post had the answer in his comment. You want to use the `string.Join()` function to put your separated values back into a delimited string. e.g. ... `Debug.Log(string.Join(",", dataValues));`

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. @quaabaam I seen Hans post but I was overthinking how to use it in my case. I didn't think it would be that easy, lol. Also someone else mentioned that I should of created a new post instead of asking another question in my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.Join()` to concatenate the separated and updated values back into a single line.

```
// string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");        
// string[] data = txt.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

// use ReadAllLines function instead of ReadAllText
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("Assets/Resources/characters.csv.txt");
foreach(string record in data)
{
    var dataValues = record.Split(',');            
    if(dataValues.Length >= 6 && dataValues[1] == trickName)
    {
        dataValues[3] = currentXP.ToString();
        dataValues[4] = currentLevel.ToString();
        dataValues[5] = maximumXP.ToString();
    }             
    // concatenate values into comma delimited line
    string outputLine = string.Join(",", dataValues);
    Debug.Log(outputLine);             
}
```

Comment: Where is the write part? The OP needs also to update the `csv` file. Also, Use the `File.ReadLines` to avoid the first split (`\n`).

Comment: @JQSOFT, OP already knows the write part, it's in his original question's link. His current issue, as I understand it, he needs to put the split and updated values back into a delimited line. OP could change the ReadAllText to ReadLines if he chooses, seems like a solid suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, and thanks for the answer @quaabaam

Comment: One slight issue I'm having when writing to the CSV file is that it adds in an extra space between a few of the records. The Log statement shows no spaces between records yet it is putting a space in between the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 5th records in the file. I tried to use a check to write only if outputLine != null or outputLine != "", but that didn't work

Comment: Try using the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEnties` option of the split function. This should remove empty lines... like so... `string[] data = txt.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Also, when checking a string for null or an empty string, a better option is to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputLine)`

Comment: I tried the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries but that did not fix the extra lines writing unfortunately.

Comment: I noticed the spaces are applied below different records when I save values to a different record from my first example where I noted a space below records 1, 2, 4, and 5

Comment: @ElloWorld, what is likely happening is a line delimiter character is likely remaining in your record. You have `\n` as your split character but new lines in Windows have two characters ,`\n\r`. What I would do, as @JQSOFT suggested, use the `ReadAllLines` function. Using `ReadAllLines` you will get back a `string[]` array of your data and not have to worry about any new line characters or splitting the line. I've edited my answer to use the `ReadAllLines` function.

Comment: Once again thank you for the solution that worked perfectly. @JQSOFT thank you for the suggestion. You guys are wizards!